# TFS Build Won't Run: TF226001: Unable to create the detail nodes for factory QueueDetails

Tags: tfsbuild, tfs-2015

Upon initiating a build that uses TFS 2015, and just recently upgraded to Update 2, builds using vNext no longer work.

I get the error:

> TF226001: Unable to create the detail nodes for factory QueueDetails

When viewing the build status in the web browser, it indicates that it is waiting for a build agent.

[image: TF226001 Error]

TFS Version: TFS 2015 Update 2 / 14.95.25122.0.

How can I get the build working again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re-configuring the build agent service on the build agent fixed the problem.

The following script is just a dump (with names replaced) of the PowerShell Build agent script that I re-ran on the build agent, using all existing configured values. I just pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd> for each one. Once the Agent had been reconfigured, queued builds started working again.

```
PS C:\TEMP> .\ConfigureAgent.cmd
An existing configuration file was detected.  This will update the local agent settings.  Do you want to also replace th
e server registration (default is N)?
Enter the name for this agent (default is Agent-AGENTCMP01)
Enter the URL for the Team Foundation Server (default is http://mytfs.mycompany.com:8080/tfs/)
Configure this agent against which agent pool? (default pool name is 'My Pool')
Enter the path of the work folder for this agent (default is 'C:\TEMP\_work')
Would you like to install the agent as a Windows Service (Y/N) (default is Y)
Enter the name of the user account to use for the service (default is MYDOMAIN\MYACCT)
Removing EventLog source vsoagent.mytfs.Agent-AGENTCMP01.
Service vsoagent.mytfs.Agent-AGENTCMP01 is being removed from the system...
Service vsoagent.mytfs.Agent-AGENTCMP01 was successfully removed from the system.
Installing service vsoagent.mytfs.Agent-AGENTCMP01...
Service vsoagent.mytfs.Agent-AGENTCMP01 has been successfully installed.
Creating EventLog source vsoagent.mytfs.Agent-AGENTCMP01 in log Application...
Configuration successful.
PS C:\TEMP>
```

Comment: I had to re-specify a number of my parameters rather than accept the defaults but this sorted my problem, thanks.

Comment: @Mike Glad it helped someone!